# AuthorizeAttribute keeps redirecting to /Account/Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, authorize-attribute

I'm trying to wrap my head around Forms Authentication in ASP.NET MVC. MVC 5 in my specific case, in case that matters.

My application doesn't use passwords, just an email address as username.

When debugging the `Login` method, I can clearly see the model is valid and my (custom) `MembershipProvider` validates the user as expected.
It then redirects to the provided `returnUrl` (for purposes of testing, I have an `AuthorizeAttribute` on /Home/About).

Sadly, I get thrown back to the `Login` view immediately so it's obvious I'm missing a fundamental element to the whole process (and, by extension, fundamental insight into the whole auth/auth process, I must admit as I rarely play around with it).

The Login method:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid && Membership.ValidateUser(model.Email, ""))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, model.RememberMe);

        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Email address unknown");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

The LoginViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

The pertinent part of the Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

What am I not seeing? Where should I be looking?

Comment: I'm no expert (at all), but when stepping through your code, does the view model become valid? Other than that, I would use the IsAuthorised instead of an authorise attribute.

Comment: @jbutler483 yes, if it didn't, there wouldn't be any redirect.

Comment: but on stepping through your code, you should also be able to see which part is failing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting your cookie using FormsAuthentication.  If you're using MVC5, they removed that type of authentication with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Look for this in your web.config.  Remove that line if you want to use FormsAuthentication.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

You may want to read this about why Microsoft removed FormsAuthentication in MVC5 and how to use OWIN instead: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can be caused by an incorrect setting of the IIS Express.

Check the `IISExpress` settings.
Either by pressing `F4` on the project or by editing the project file `*.csproj`.

1. Set property `Anonymous Authentication` to `Enabled`;
2. Set property `Windows Authentication` to `Disabled`.

OR edit configuration to:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
  <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
```